# Deep nesting functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I cannot find an proper example for the love of my life on how to do this or even if this is possible. Based on my pieced together understanding from fragments of exmaples, I have come up with the following structure

```
         var t = function()
         {
             this.nestedOne = function()
             {
                 this.nest = function()
                 {
                     alert("here");
                 }
             }
         } 
         t.nestedOne.nest();
```

However this is not working (obviously). I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: I am trying to emulate nested classes as normally seen in programming languages. It makes OOP very organized and libraries much more organized. I know that JavaScript is not really built for complex OOP, but regardless it helps. JavaScript has a very unorthodox approach to functions but I can completely see why it is so powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is simply done with:

```
var t = {
    nestedOne: {
        nest: function() {
            alert('here');
        }
    }
};
```

Your code otherwise doesn't make sense. `this` inside function doesn't refer to the function itself, it refers to the object context that the function is invoked in. And you are not even invoking the functions in your code.

If I say `obj.func()` then `this` inside `func` will be `obj` for that call. So assigning `this.asd = true` will assign `true` to that object's `"asd"` property.

If you wanted to do a nested class, it looks very different:

```
ClassA = (function() {
   function ClassA() {

   }

   ClassA.prototype.method1 = function() {

   };

   function ClassB() {

   }

   ClassB.prototype.method1 = function() {

   };

   return ClassA;
}())
```

only ClassA can now make instances of ClassB. This should achieve same goals as nested classes in java.

Comment: You've provided an answer that shows him a cleaner way to do what people typically want, but he looks confused by the way functions work in general (the code inside hasn't been run yet) Do you want to include a blurb about it?

Comment: @Incognito tbh, his understanding is so screwed I have no idea what to do here.

Comment: I am getting the hang of it. For someone coming out of C#/Java/C++ simply appending functions to other functions on the fly is a bit strange but is proving to be quite powerful.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov There is no advantage in appending functions to other functions. You are using the functions for their object nature (functions are exactly like objects, except they can be invoked with the `()` operator. You might even say they are callable objects.), so you might as well use plain objects which have niftier syntax.

Comment: Maybe it is the issue with tutorials? Even with objects, you can simply say myObject.myFunction = function() {} which can happen at any point in your script as long as its after the myObject=new Object(). That is, according to this tutorial http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml

Comment: @SergueiFedorov any tutorial using `new Object()` is not worth reading. You can use `var myObject = {myFunction: function(){}`

Comment: @Esailija I'm not sure either or I would have said it already. Perhaps our tag wiki is the best starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Comment: @Esailija is it me or a lot of Tutorials on JavaScript don't do a very good job at teaching proper JavaScript? JavaScript has its own kind of approach to scripting and I feel like a lot of tutorial point out how things are and not why it takes a certain syntax approach.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov MDN is actually pretty good, for instance https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Comment: To a degree emulating classes using functions reminds me of how you can emulate classes using function pointers :P

Comment: Well yeah it's pretty crap but what you gonna do :)

Comment: Yea I guess it sucks but at the same time you gotta remember that its not supposed to be a programming language but rather an easy to use scripting language. To add to that if you can use functions like that then why not? I can't imagine too many people who use javascript get really complex with classes anyways and being able to simply append new functions to libraries like JQuery is pretty damn nice.

Answer (score 2):

See http://jsfiddle.net/CstUH/

```
function t(){
     function f(){
         this.nest = function()
         {
             alert("here");
         }
     }
     this.nestedOne = new f();
 }
var myt=new t();
myt.nestedOne.nest()
```

**Edit 1:**

You can also use

```
new t().nestedOne.nest()
```

instead of

```
var myt=new t();
myt.nestedOne.nest()
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/CstUH/1/)

**Edit 2:**

Or even more condensed:

```
function t(){
    this.nestedOne = new function(){
        this.nest = function(){
            alert("here");
        }
    }
}
new t().nestedOne.nest()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CstUH/2/

Answer (score 1):

In JS functions are **prime class objects**, and you can access them directly in the code [i.e. without using reflection or so].

The code you put inside `t` body would be performed when actually executing `t`:

```
t();
```

You wrote `t.nestedOne,nest()`, but `t` has no `nestedOne` property - you should do like this:

```
var t = {

    nestedOne : {

        nest : function()
        {

            alert("here");

        }        

    }

};

t.nestedOne.nest();                ​
```

I advice you to have a trip on [John Resig's Learning Advanced JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) tutorial, it was very enlightening for me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple callback handler I wrote today as an example of how I do deep nesting. I apologize if it's not the bees knees when it comes to code style, it made the concept a little clearer for me.

```
    function test () {
      this.that = this;
      this.root = this;

      this.jCallback = new Array(new Array()); // 2d
      this.jCallbackCount = -1;
      this.str = "hello";


      // Callback handler... 
      this.command = {
        that : this, // let's keep a reference to who's above us on the food chain
        root : this.root, // takes us back to the main object

        // add : function() { var that = this; console.log(that.that.str); },
        add : function(targetFnc, newFunc) { 
            var that = this; 
            var home = that.that; // pretty much root but left in as an example of chain traversal.
            var root = this.root; // useful for climbing back up the function chain

            // console.log(that.that.str); 
            home.jCallbackCount++;
            // target, addon, active
            home.jCallback[home.jCallback.length] =  { 'targetFunc' : targetFnc,  'newFunc' : newFunc,  'active' : true, 'id': home.jCallbackCount};

            console.log('cbacklength: ' + home.jCallback.length);
            console.log('added callback targetFunction:[' + targetFnc + ']');

            return home.jCallbackCount; // if we want to delete this later...      
        },

        run : function(targetFnc) {
            var that = this; 
            var home = that.that;
            console.log('running callback check for: ' + targetFnc + '  There is : ' + (home.jCallbackCount + 1) + 'in queue.');
            console.log('length of callbacks is ' + home.jCallback.length);

            for(i=0;i < home.jCallback.length - 1;i++)
            {
              console.log('checking array for a matching callback [' + targetFnc + ']...');
              console.log('current item: ' + home.jCallback[i]['targetFunc'] );
              if( home.jCallback[i]['targetFunc'] == targetFnc )
              {
                 // matched! 
                home.jCallback[i]['newFunc']();
              }

                // console.log(that.that.jCallback[i].targetFunction);
            }
        }
      };

    }

    test.prototype = {
      say : function () {
        var that = this;
        console.log('inside');
        // that.command('doSay');
        that.command.run('doSay');
        console.log(that.str);
      }


    } // end proto



    // BEGIN TESTING **************************************************************************
    // BEGIN TESTING **************************************************************************
    // BEGIN TESTING **************************************************************************
    var testing = new test();


    testing.command.add('doSay', function () { console.log('213123123'); } );
    testing.command.add('doSay', function () { console.log('12sad31'); } );
    testing.command.add('doSay', function () { console.log('asdascccc'); } );


    testing.say();
```

live:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ps5Uf/

- note: to view console output, just open inspector in chrome and click on the "console" tab.